# Django model calculated property

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model that's a job application, with 3 states.

Accepted: explicitly accepted 
Rejected: explicitly rejected 
Pending: neither explicitly accepted nor rejected

It makes sense for me to define an `accepted` and a `rejected` fields for my model, so I can explicitly set them. But the `pending` property is conditioned based on the other two... so setting a property for it doesn't make sense.

I could just write a method for it, like `job.pending()` that returns a boolean which is just `( not accepted ) and (not rejected)`. But is there some way to just do `job.pending` without writing a method?

Just curious...

Comment: You can define a [Managed Attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/glossary/#term-property)

Comment: Why are you reluctant to have a `pending()` method?

Comment: Not "reluctant", just curious. I do agree that `pending()` would be the most elegant thing to do, since it's the least amount of work and doesn't break any default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `save()` method to do something like this, so that every time you change your job model it recalculates pending. Although I agree with limelights that the `pending()` method isn't bad either.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    accepted = ...
    reject = ...
    pending = ... (Boolean Fields)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pending = (not self.accepted) and (not self.rejected)
        super(Job, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods